# A javascript that sets a height/margin if img is a certain height

Tags: javascript, image, height, margin, tumblr

Basically what I want to do, is set a img height to 100% if it is shorter than 160px/10em on screen. I have no experience with javascript though. After a few googles this is what I came up.

```
if ($('#Photo_Crop img').height() < 160) {
    then ('#Photo_Crop img').style.height = "100%";}
```

However surprising it does not work. 
Here is the html is use.

```
<div id="Photo_Crop"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" /></div>
```

And this is the css.

```
    #Photo_Crop {
    height:64%;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

#Photo_Crop img {
    transition:margin-bottom 0.333s, margin-top 0.333s;
    margin-bottom:-16%;
    margin-top:-16%;
    z-index:-1;
}

#Photo_Crop:hover {
    height:100%;
}

#Photo_Crop img:hover {
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
}
```

As you can see my code crops a picture until you hover over it then it shows the entire picture.This is to save space on a Tumblr blog. It works great unless you get a really wide picture, for example a panorama because the panorama will be cropped to and look way to small. Any help solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "then" in javascript. Also you forgot the second $-sign in front of the second brackets and then i guess you can not use "100%" to check the height.

Comment: if ($('#Photo_Crop img').height() < 160) {
        ($('#Photo_Crop img').style.margin() = "0";)
}

It still doesn't work though

Comment: you propably should learn javascript first.
and you mix jquery and dom-javascript ..

Comment: I probably should yeah. But I do not have enough time to do so right now.

Comment: try: if ($('#Photo_Crop img').height() < 160) { $('#Photo_Crop img').css({margin : 0}); }
Hope that helps.